# Delegate methods of NSTextField using NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, delegates

I have an NSTokenField in a window.  I am using it to store tags related to a Core Data object.  Right now I have it set up such that I can add tags to the objects, but I cannot delete them.  I need a delegate method on the NSTokenField that can let me know when the user has moved the focus out of the NSTokenField.  Since NSTokenField is a subclass of NSTextField I figured that I could use its delegate methods.  It has two that I think could be useful:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

I set my controller class as the delegate of my NSTokenField and put both of these methods into my controller class.  I put a basic NSLog into each of them and neither is triggered when I interact with the NSTokenField.  I am guessing it has something to do with NSNotification.  How do I activate these methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NSTokenField` invokes the `controlTextDidChange:` and the `controlTextDidEndEditing:` notifications; change the two methods above, implementing them as:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    //Code here..
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    //Code here..
}
```