# NSTokenField not firing action

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, action, nstokenfield

I have an `NSTokenField` to add tags to an object (a document). I would like to update the object with new tags the moment a token is added to the token field (when a tokenising character is typed). Unfortunately this does not seem to work.
The `NSTokenField` is connected to an action in my controller but this action method is never called.

I also have a `NSTextField` connected in the same way to the controller and its action method in the controller is called.

I've also tried this with key value observing:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [tokenField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"objectValue" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}


- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([object isEqual:tokenField]){
        NSLog(@"Tokens changed");
    }
}
```

but this action is only called when I programatically change the tokens.

How can I be notified when the tokens in the `tokenField` are changed?

Comment: You can take a look at the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852038/delegate-methods-of-nstextfield-using-nsnotification

Comment: @DavidMangon Thank you. Unfortunately it is not a complete solution because I need to detect when a new token is added. '- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification' is called when a character is entered and also when a tokenising character is added. The stringValue does not however show the added tokenizing character and the notification is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NSTokenField` action selector isn't called the moment a new tag is created. Depending on the setting you've gone with in *Interface Builder*, it's called either when you hit enter to end editing (*Send On Enter Only*) , or when you end editing some other way (*Send On End Editing*). To get the fine control you're after you'll need another approach.

---

The blue *tags* that appear when a tokenising character is added to the token field are called text attachments (instances of `NSTextAttachment`). One way of working out when tags are being added/removed from your token field is to track changes to the number of these objects contained in the token field's underlying attributed string.

To get access to the relevant attributed string you need to get hold of the *fieldEditor's* `layoutManager` - the object which ultimately supplies the string that appears in the text-view. Once you've got it, each time you get a `controlTextDidChange:` message, count up the number of text attachments in the `string` representation of its `attributedString`. If the number this time around is greater than the number recorded in the previous count, a tag has just been added.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) NSLayoutManager *lm;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger tokenCount;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

// The text in the fieldEditor has changed. If the number of attachments in the
// layoutManager's attributedString has changed, either a new tag has been added,
// or an existing tag has been deleted.
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {
    NSUInteger updatedCount = [self countAttachmentsInAttributedString:self.lm.attributedString];
    if (updatedCount > self.tokenCount) {
        NSLog(@"ADDED");
        self.tokenCount = updatedCount;
    } else if (updatedCount < self.tokenCount) {
        NSLog(@"REMOVED");
        self.tokenCount = updatedCount;
    }
}

// About to start editing - get access to the fieldEditor's layoutManager
-(BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor {
    self.lm = [(NSTextView *)fieldEditor layoutManager];
    return YES;
}

// Iterate through the characters in an attributed string looking for occurrences of
// the NSAttachmentCharacter.
- (NSInteger)countAttachmentsInAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString {
    NSString *string = [attributedString string];
    NSUInteger maxIndex = string.length - 1;
    NSUInteger counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex + 1; i++) {
        if ([string characterAtIndex:i] == NSAttachmentCharacter) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where did you get all this info from? Is there an Apple link?

Comment: This answer doesn't refer to any single source; I pieced it together from various Apple pages relating to the text system - most notably doc's concerning text layout, attributed strings, and of course the ``NSTokenField`` class reference. If you think about it, ``NSTokenField`` is a subclass of ``NSTextField``, so the content is either a string or an attributed string. It's clearly not simply a string, which leaves just one option! All you need to do then is work out how ``NSTextAttachment`` instances are represented in attributed strings, and then you can count them.

Answer (score 1):

A port of @paul-patterson's code to Swift 3:

```
override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    guard let fieldEditor = self.tokenField.currentEditor() as? NSTextView,
        let layoutManager = fieldEditor.layoutManager
        else { return }

    func countAttachments(attributedString: NSAttributedString) -> Int {

        let string = attributedString.string as NSString
        let maxIndex = string.length - 1
        var counter = 0

        for i in 0..<maxIndex {
            if string.character(at: i) == unichar(NSAttachmentCharacter) {
                counter += 1
            }
        }

        return counter
    }

    let currentCount = countAttachments(attributedString: layoutManager.attributedString())
    // cache count or act on it directly
}
```

---

Oddly enough, the following does *not* produce the expected outcome in Swift:

```
layoutManager.attributedString().string
    .split(by: Character(UnicodeScalar(NSAttachmentCharacter)!)).count
```

Instead, it returns 0 when the user is not typing and 1 when a token is being edited.

```
let isEditing = layoutManager.attributedString().string
    .split(by: Character(UnicodeScalar(NSAttachmentCharacter)!)).count == 1
```

With the combination of both approaches, you could write a custom "did add/remove token" callback using a state machine. (I don't think this is a very safe way to implement that, though.)

- Track the count of tokens with `countAttachments(attributedString:)`.
- Use `isEditing` to check ...

  1. if the user started adding a new note (new count > old count && isEditing == true)
  2. if the user started editing an existing note (new count == old count && isEditing == true)
  3. if the user finished a token (oldIsEditing == true && newIsEditing == false)